# Let's substitute [substitute] with [substitution]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

**tl;dr please synonym**

[substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substitute) -> [substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substitution)

---

- [substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substitution) - 587 questions, has a (crappy) wiki
- [substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substitute) - 151 questions, no wiki

There's also

- [string-substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-substitution), which has 66 questions and a wiki

  - However, I imagine it would be inappropriate for some of those first questions.

The tag is sort of a meta tag, so perhaps it should be burninated (I'm on the fence), but for now this is just a synonym request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** [substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substitute) is synonymised to [substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substitution)

---

I've been through the [substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substitute) posts. They're referencing a language/software specific function (such as SQL/R/Excel Formula/etc...) but are referring to the process of [substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/substitution) in general. The other tags clarify the context.

This follows the same logic as [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compile)/[compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiling) -> [compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compilation) and also auto-completes as expected so shouldn't cause surprises.

---

It looks like [string-substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string-substitution) is somewhat redundant as its intended use can be expressed via other tags sufficiently well - but it will need going through and manually handled.